# jQuery fade in / fade out animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Well I have a problem that I don't really know how to solve. I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript. I use jQuery to animate a text.

My problem is that I want to make an object fade out/in when scrolled out of view.
Opacity of the element changes but I'm not sure how to "zoom" it in at the same time...

I would want to do this in the way which will allow me to use a standard css transform.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 150);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://simply-design.ml/img/start1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.header-sec {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 25px 0px;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.header-sec h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.header-sec .p1 {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.space {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header1">
  <section class="header-sec">
    <center class="top">
      <h1>TITLE</h1>
      <div style="height: 3px; width: 100px; background-color: #000; margin: 30px;"></div>
      <p class="p1">subtitle here</p>
    </center>
  </section>
</header>

<section class="space"></section>
```

Comment: `transform:scale();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scale property of transform like this

```
    var abc = 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 150;
    $(".top").css("opacity", abc);
    $(".top").css("transform", "scale(" + abc + ")");
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://simply-design.ml/img/start1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.header-sec {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 25px 0px;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.header-sec h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.header-sec .p1 {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.space {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header1">
  <section class="header-sec">
    <center class="top">
      <h1>TITLE</h1>
      <div style="height: 3px; width: 100px; background-color: #000; margin: 30px;"></div>
      <p class="p1">subtitle here</p>
    </center>
  </section>
</header>

<section class="space"></section>
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var abc = 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 150;
    $(".top").css("opacity", abc);
    $(".top").css("transform", "scale(" + abc + ")");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats what I wanted. U just didn''t know how to do this correctly.

Comment: well... i still dont know how to manupulate the values of this method... Could you please show me how to do it? :)

Comment: I only want to know where do i "put" some numbers to actually make it scale. somehow it doesnt work for me :/

Comment: Put it same as you did with the opacity.